# How would I go about in comparing whether one string input is a prefix of the second string input?

Tags: python, string, prefix

Say for example the user inputs 'turn' as string 1 and for string 2 they input 'turnover'. How would I create a code in which it would compare each character of both strings and their indexes. So far I've got something like this in progress

```
string_1 = str(input("Insert first string:"))
string_2 = str(input("Insert second string:"))

def prefixes(a,b):
  if len(b) < len(a):
    return False
  else:
    for i in range(len(b)):

prefixes(string_1,string_2)
```

Comment: You might like [startswith()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `startswith()`:

```
string_1 = str(input("Insert first string:"))
string_2 = str(input("Insert second string:"))

if string_2.startswith(string_1):
    # Your code here
```

Note that `startswith()` can also accept parameters for the indices to start and stop the comparison at, if you need that functionality.

---

As commented on the question by [Mark Mayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3874623/mark-meyer), more information is available on string  methods [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith).

---

**Edit**: You asked for a way to do this using a `for` loop. This assumes you want to check if `string_2` starts with `string_1`.

```
string_1 = str(input("Insert first string:"))
string_2 = str(input("Insert second string:"))

def prefix_check(short, long);
    for index in range(min(len(short), len(long))):
        if short[index] != long[index]:
            return false
    return true

print(prefix_check(string_1, string_2))
```

Comment: How would I go about without using the startwith() method and only using for loop

Comment: @Adamtoo What do you mean? You don’t need a for loop unless of course you are comparing multiple pairs of strings. You could use a for loop to recreate you own version of `startswith()` of course, by iterating through the letters.

Comment: By iterating yes, how would I be able to do this. Would I need to use an accumulator variable?

Comment: @Adamtoo You could just compare the letters at each index in each iteration and return false if they are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you are thinking to extract a *common prefix of two input strings*, you could use `zip()` in combination with [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)

```
from itertools import takewhile


def prefixes(a, b):
    return ''.join(x for x, _ in takewhile(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], zip(a, b)))


string_1 = str(input("Insert first string:"))
string_2 = str(input("Insert second string:"))

print(prefixes(string_1, string_2))
```

Sample output:

```
Insert first string: prepare
Insert second string: preparation
prepar
```